# Remove row from a DataGridView

Tags: .net, vb.net, datagridview

I have a DataGridView with 7 cells, in every cell I'm into if i press escape the current row is removed thou an event i made named `Public Event EscapeOnFirstRowPressed` with no problem, and brings me the control to each initial state.

The general idea of this process is when all the cells are fulfilled then

- Write the Data into a SQL table and
- Remove the current row, so the user is now ready to import new data.

Since the Write procedure is OK I turn my interest to remove of the row.

I say this action needs to call it either from `RowValidated` sub or from `CellEnter` (which take place when I leave the current row and gets to the next row). But in either place if I put the command

```
If Not DGV.CurrentCell.EditedFormattedValue = "" Then
            If Not DGV.Rows(RowIndex).IsNewRow Then
                DGV.Rows.RemoveAt(RowIndex)
                DGV.Refresh()
            End If

        ElseIf DGV.CurrentCell.EditedFormattedValue = Nothing Then
            If Not DGV.Rows(RowIndex).IsNewRow Then
                DGV.Rows.RemoveAt(RowIndex)
                DGV.Refresh()
            End If
        End If
```

I receive the following error

```
DGV.Rows.RemoveAt(0) {"Operation cannot be performed in this event handler."}
```

I was try another process to this action. I try to simulate the KeyPress action by giving the following command

```
Dim myKeyData As System.Windows.Forms.Keys
Dim myMsg As System.Windows.Forms.Message
  myKeyData = Keys.Escape
ProcessCmdKey(myMsg, myKeyData)
```

But I receive the same error, when the pointer comes to execute the same instruction which executed when I press the Esc key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can execute code in the next message loop, after the event handler finishes, by calling `BeginInvoke`.

Comment: Thanks for the attention, please be more specific. When i will do that? At the end of CellValidated? or After RowValidated? And please can you assist me of how to use the BeginInvocke because I was try to do it but I couldn' make any positive result.

Comment: Call `BeginInvoke` and pass a delegate that deletes the row.

Comment: You are the best in Town, solved successfully my issue. I wish to have the ability to give you more votes. Thanks again